# How to proceed with induction step of induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$$
P(n): (1+a)^n \geq 1 + a(n - 1)
\\
a \geq 0
$$

I already proved its base case with n = 1, which is pretty simple. However, I am confused on how to proceed with my induction step of

$$
P(n+1): (1+a)^{n+1} \geq 1 + a(n)
\\
P(n+1): (1+a)^n(1+a) \geq 1 + a(n) 
$$

Any tips on what to do next? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assume $a \ge 0$ for the case $n=1$ to be true.

Note we must prove $(1+a(n-1))(1+a) \ge 1+a(n)$. Let $n=t+1$.

This implies that we must prove that $a^2t + a(t+1) +1 \ge 1+a(t+1)$, which follows from $a \ge 0$, $t \ge 0$.

Comment: Yep, edited. This proves for all $n \geq 1$ right because we proved n = 1 true in base case and $n = 1 + t, t \geq 0$?

Comment: @op_finales Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $P(n)$ is true as per the induction hypothesis.

Hence $(1+a)^n \ge 1+a(n-1)$

Now for $P(n+1)$,

$$(1+a)^{n+1}=(1+a)^n(1+a)\ge \{1+a(n-1)\}(1+a) \\= 1+a(n-1)+a+a^2(n-1) \ge 1+an$$

since $a^2(n-1)$ is always positive for $n > 1$.

Hence $P(n+1)$ is true.

Comment: I thought the induction hypothesis has to be the same as the given. Why is it 1 + an instead of 1 + a (n-1)

Comment: I think $P(n)$ is $(1+a)^n \geq 1 + a(n -1)$.

Comment: @op_finales It was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Thanks for helping. typo corrected.